# Calling subroutine from another class, contains operations like getActionBar.removeTab() which can't be static

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm within a fragment calling a subroutine from another class which contains getActionBar.removeTab() but as I'm within a fragment the method I'm calling needs to be static but getActionBar cannot be contained within a static method. Which leaves me a little out of my depth. Any ideas?

**Purpose**

The point of the below code is so within the fragment I can remove tabs when neccersy from the class *OtherClass*

Code:

```
public class Example extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
OtherClass.SubWhichWontWork(); }


public class OtherClass extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {

public void SubWhichWontWork() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
if (blabla > other){
getActionBar().removeTabAt(numtabbar);}

}
```

Comment: From fragment you can call getActivity() and cast it to your, specific activity and call method from this activity... or you can play with getAtivity().getActionBar() from fragment, too

Comment: Could you please explain that with an example? thanks :-)

Comment: since `OtherClass` extends `Activity` and with assumption that `Example` fragment is used inside `OtherClass` - you can use `((OtherClass)getActivity()).SubWhichWontWork();` inside fragment

Comment: Awesome :-)

Copy you're answer into "Answer your Question" and I'll select yours

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since `OtherClass` extends `Activity` and with assumption that `Example` fragment is used inside `OtherClass` you can use `((OtherClass)getActivity()).SubWhichWontWork();` inside `onCreateView` of `Example` class

Comment: That's a **bad** practice -1